# ros2: turtlebot3 gazebo /scan topic subscriber is not calling the callback function

Tags: ros, gazebo, ros2, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to simply subscribe to `/scan` topic after launching `turtlebot3_world.py` launch file in [turtlebot3_gazebo](https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/turtlebot3_simulations/tree/master/turtlebot3_gazebo) pkg. For that I am creating a ros2 node which subscribes to /scan topic and logs it into the console.

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:

/scan works from terminal using `ros2 topic echo /scan`  but when run my pkg it simple not calling the callback function. This is how my subscriber class looks like.

```
class ScanPrinter:public rclcpp::Node{
public:

ScanPrinter():Node("scan_printer"){
    sub_ = this->create_subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan>(
    "scan",
    rclcpp::QoS(rclcpp::KeepLast(10)),
    std::bind(&ScanPrinter::LaserCallback, this, std::placeholders::_1)
    );
}

private:
void LaserCallback(const sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan::SharedPtr msg){
    RCLCPP_INFO(this->get_logger(), std::to_string(msg->ranges[90]).c_str());
}
rclcpp::Subscription<sensor_msgs::msg::LaserScan>::SharedPtr sub_;
};
```

- Operating System:

  - Ubuntu 18.04
- Version or commit hash:

  - Compiled from github <!-- from source: output of `git -C navigation2 rev-parse HEAD
    apt binaries: output of: dpkg-query --show "ros-$ROS_DISTRO-navigation2"
                              or: dpkg-query --show "ros-$ROS_DISTRO-nav2-*" -->
- DDS implementation:

  - Default

##### Steps I do in order

- `export TURTLEBOT3_MODEL=burger`
- `export GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH=$GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH:<PATH/TO/MODELS>`
- I launch the `turtlebot3_world.launch.py` file which opens up the gazebo with the spawned turtle bot.
- I try to run my subscriber node and it prints nothing on the console log, as it suppose to according to the `LaseCallback` function. By which I deduce that its not calling the call back function.
- Then I tried `ros2 topic echo /scan` and it prints the message correctly.
- Then I tried to see if my subscribers has really subscribed this topic by `ros2 topic info /scan` and then it prints `publisher: 1, subscriber 1` by which I deduce it does.
- Then I tried to subscribe custom string publisher by making necessary changes in the code, and it behaves perfectly.

I don't know what is wrong here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334649/ros2:-turtlebot3-gazebo-/scan-topic-subscriber-is-not-calling-the-callback-function/) by [shivaang12](https://answers.ros.org/users/27030/shivaang12/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2019-10-05

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-10-06**:
It's unlikely members here will analyse your complete package for you -- especially if you just post a link here. We don't run a debugging service here.

Please provide some excerpts of your code, especially the parts having to do with creating subscribers, an overview of the topics that do exist, a description of how you start everything (also: in what order), versions of things like Fast-RTPS (or any other DDS implementation you are using), etc, etc.

**Comment by [shivaang12](https://answers.ros.org/users/27030/shivaang12/) on 2019-10-06**:
Sorry, I couldn't figured out earlier how to post code, which is why I provided the link. But I made the necessary changes as per you suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I made it work at the end. The  `/scan` topic publishes the data with Sensor QoS profile, `qos_profile_sensor_data`.  So it is mandatory to use `qos_profile_sensor_data` QoS profile in the subscriber.

---

Originally posted by [shivaang12](https://answers.ros.org/users/27030/shivaang12/) with karma: 61 on 2019-10-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [zmk5](https://answers.ros.org/users/44691/zmk5/) on 2019-10-15**:
This worked for me! Thank you!

For those that need help with this in python it should be: `rclpy.qos.qos_profile_sensor_data`

For C++, it should be: `rmw_qos_profile_sensor_data`

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also take a look at the Dolly demo for Gazebo (https://github.com/chapulina/dolly). They are using `rclcpp::QoS(rclcpp::SystemDefaultsQoS())`.

---

Originally posted by [greggScutum](https://answers.ros.org/users/49951/greggscutum/) with karma: 21 on 2019-12-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2